# Refresh Cascading dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 cascading dropdown in my page. I also use the below code to display --Select-- for all two dropdowns in page load.

```
ddlID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select ID--", "0"));
ddlID.SelectedIndex = 0;
ddlName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--", "0"));
ddlName.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

But when I select any of the value in ID dropdown list then --Select Name-- is not getting displayed. Also when I select --Select ID-- again then Name dropdowns doesn't have any values.

Comment: can you paste your whole your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this attribute

```
AppendDataBoundItems="true"
```

to your dropdonws.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="..." ...AppendDataBoundItems="true"/>
```